# Function for Labelling Icons per category in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have geographic coordinates that I display to a Leaflet Map. Each feature is ether in the Category (2018, Never Covered or Other periods).

I would like to create a simple function to have different colors for my categories.

Whats the most simple way to do that?

Ive joined my blockbuilder: http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/5678103bddc3c05c5410e1579b62944a

Can i call a function directly after adding my markers ?

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([10.762622, 106.660172], 13);
var pharmaciesMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup();

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

Any examples will be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to select the appropriate icon beforehand and call it when you *instantiate* the marker. Since the shipped marker is blue, you might find this resource useful: [leaflet-color-markers](https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers). You would then write up a function that selects the appropriate marker color:

```js
function colorMarker(category) {
  switch (category) {
    /*Icons need to be defined beforehand 
      according to leaflet-color-marker documentation*/
    case '2018':            return greenIcon; break; 
    case 'Never Covered':   return yellowIcon; break;
    case 'Other periods':   return redIcon; break;
  }
}

var marker = L.marker([+d.lat, +d.lng], { icon: colorMarker(d.category) })
```